# mysql query on many to many outer joins produce duplicates

Tags: mysql

A query outer join problem.
I have these three tables:
Table article(
id,
articletitle, articletext) 
 - and so on. The other columns do not matter here.
Table category(
id,
name)
Table articlecategory(
articleid,
categoryid,
index articleid, categoryid)
When I execute the following query I get duplicates for any article that has more than one category
Query:

```
SELECT category.name AS categoryname
     , article.id as articleid, article.articletitle  AS articletitle, article.articletext as articletext, article.articlev as articlev, article.visible as visible
     , GROUP_CONCAT(othercategory.name) AS othercategories
  FROM category
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN articlecategory
    ON articlecategory.categoryid = category.id
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN article
    ON article.id = articlecategory.articleid
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN articlecategory AS otherarticlecategory
    ON otherarticlecategory.articleid = articlecategory.articleid
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN category AS othercategory
    ON othercategory.id = otherarticlecategory.categoryid

GROUP
    BY category.name ASC
     , article.articletitle  ASC';
```

The results are something like this:

```
foreach
article 1
othercategory = category(s) finishing, sanding
article 1
category(s) finishing, sanding
article2
category(s) tips
article 3
category(s) tips, informational
article 3
category(s) tips, informational
endforeach
```

I did not write this query. The person who did I guess has gotten too busy to respond back. So I need some help but I am not smart enough for hints. So please be specific. I think I know what the problem is but I do not have enough experience to fix it.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: When one is blind and use a screen reader  forums can be difficult at best. Just sayin, not complainin. I will try to figure out how to do as you ask. All though this is my go to site for help, I have never asked a question here for this very reason.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` should get rid of the duplicates. I also noticed that in your existing `GROUP BY` you should be using the aliases instead of the fully qualified name.

Try adding article id to the `GROUP BY`.

```
GROUP BY categoryname ASC, articletitle  ASC, articleid ASC
```

Comment: if I group by article.id first then I have no duplicates. But then the sort order is not by category.

Comment: In that case, group by `articleid` last. Alternatively, you can do an `order by categoryname` after your group by.